# How to optimize a list search in SML/NJ?

Tags: arrays, list, tuples, time-complexity, sml

I am writing a piece of code in SML/NJ and need, at some point, to access a list, which I have already created. I know that, in C, for example, accessing an array takes constant time. So, I thought that that would be the case for ML as well. Apparently, however, the built-in List.nth(l,i) function has a complexity that is linear to the size of the list given as argument.

I then turned to arrays, but I think that the Array.sub function has, also, linear complexity.

So, given the fact the accesing a tuple, like #2(12,5.6,"foo"), has an O(1) complexity, I would like to ask whether there is a way, I could use a tuple, instead of a list,but access it dynamically.

For example, say I want to write a function that takes a tuple, with only boolean values, and an integer n, and returns True if the n-th element of the tuple is true.Something like:

```
fun isTrue (n,tup) =
if #n(tup) then true
else false;
```

I know this isn't valid SML, so is there a way to write such a function?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time!

Comment: "I think that the Array.sub function has, also, linear complexity." Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sml function has O(1) complexity, so feel free to use it! 
e.x.

```
`fun isTrue (n,tup) =
if Array.sub(tup,n) then true
else false;`
```

As far as the tuple is concerned, you can only use a specific number, not a variable in a tuple. 
e.x.
   `fun isTrue (n,tup) = 
    if #2 (tup) then true
    else false;`

Comment: `if ... then true else false` is redundant. If your goal is to enforce that `...` is a Boolean, then you can just use `: bool`.